# How to get the percentage of one value across a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with something simple:

| Country | % Renewable |
| --- | --- |
| USA | 100 |
| Belgium | 90 |
| UK | 103 |

I need to get two things:

1. Which country has the biggest Energy; I did this:

```py
    df = df.sort_values(by=['% Renewable'],ascending=False).head(1)
```

2. the percentage of that value across all countries and return it in a tuple with `(Country Name, %)`

How can I achieve this?

Update 1: I did this:

```
def answer_six():
    df = answer_one()
    #print(df)
    suma = df['% Renewable'].sum()
    top3 = df['% Renewable'].nlargest(1)
    tups = list(zip(top3.index, top3.div(suma)*100))
    return tups
```

However the autograder says I need to return a tuple, isnt it already?

Comment: How looks expected output in form `(Country Name, %)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max` and then for tuples zip divided column and convert to list:

```
top = df['% Renewable'].max()
print (top)
103
```

If `Country` is index and need top3 countries use:

```
top3 = df['% Renewable'].nlargest(3)
tups = list(zip(top3.index, top3))
print (tups)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that Country is actually the index, how can I get the index calue in this case?

Comment: I should return only the top country int the tuple not all countries.

Comment: @LuisValencia - Answer was changed.

Comment: please see my update, its not returning a tuple?

Comment: @LuisValencia - Hmmm, you forget for `3` in `df['% Renewable'].nlargest(1)`, need `df['% Renewable'].nlargest(3)`, and then division is necessary? Not only `list(zip(top3.index, top3))` ?

Comment: what is nlargest?(3)? I though it would return the top 3 countries

Comment: I wrote the question incorrectly, I should return one tuple with one country, and the percentage of renewable energy that country has between all the other countries. makes snese?

Comment: @LuisValencia - If use `df['% Renewable'].nlargest(3)` get top `%` and if index is `country` get indices of top3 countries.

Comment: @LuisValencia - Not sure if understand, need divide by sum? `tups = list(zip(top3.index, top3.div(df['% Renewable'].sum())))` ?

Comment: nevermind about my last comment, I already get this: [('Brazil', 69.64803)].  However the autograder says this is not a tuple.

Comment: @LuisValencia - Maybe need tuple of top3 countries like `tuple(df['% Renewable'].nlargest(3).index.tolist())`

Comment: @LuisValencia - Because `[('Brazil', 69.64803)]` is list of tuple

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your df contains one column of 'country' and another column of '% Renewable'.
After you have done sorting (without using head(1)):

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['% Renewable'],ascending=False)
```

simply use a for loop:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    c = (df.loc[i,'country'],df.loc[i,'% Renewable'])
    print(c)
```

If you want to save as a tuple:

```
t = list(zip(df['country'],df['% Renewable']))
print(t)
```

If you are only interested in printing as in (country,% Renewable), then simply use list comprehension:

```
[print(df.loc[i,'country'],df.loc[i,'% Renewable']) for i in range(len(df))]
```

Since you have already sorted the df, it will print in descending order.